# Aligning Shape's Center to JPanel's Center

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, java-2d, paintcomponent

I have been trying to align my java2d shape's center to the JPanel's center with no success. I was able to do it for an image and many 2D shapes like parallelogram using getBounds method  but not for rhombus though all of them follow the same pattern. Drastically, when I prepared an SSCCE out of the actual project I could align none of them correctly. 
I've written a drawShape method for drawing shapes on center. I didn't understand where I'm going wrong.
This is SSCCE:

```
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.geom.*;
            import java.util.*;
            import javax.swing.*;
            public class TestPanel extends JPanel{
                    Point a,b,c,d;
                    Shape trapezium,parallelogram;
                    Random random=new Random();
                    public TestPanel(){
                        a=new Point();
                        b=new Point();
                        c=new Point();
                        d=new Point();
                        rhombusFactory(a,b,c,d);
                        trapezium=getQuadrilateral(a,b,c,d);


                    }
                    private void rhombusFactory(Point a,Point b,Point c,Point d)
                    {       int width=random.nextInt(200-100)+100;
                            int height=random.nextInt(150-50)+50;
                            a.x=0;
                            a.y=0;
                            b.x=a.x+width/2;
                            b.y=a.y+height/2;
                            c.x=a.x+width;
                            c.y=a.y;
                            d.x=a.x+width/2;
                            d.y=a.y-height/2;
                    }
                    private void parallelogramFactory(Point a,Point b,Point c,Point d){
                        int l1=random.nextInt(200-100)+100;
                        int l2=random.nextInt(150-70)+70;
                        int offset=(random.nextInt(2)==0?-1:1)*(random.nextInt(50-20)+20);
                        a.x=0;
                        a.y=0;
                        b.x=a.x+l1;
                        b.y=a.y;
                        d.x=a.x+offset;
                        d.y=a.y+l2;
                        c.x=d.x+l1;
                        c.y=d.y;
                }
                     private Shape getQuadrilateral(Point a,Point b,Point c,Point d){
                         GeneralPath gp=new GeneralPath();
                         gp.moveTo(a.x,a.y);
                         gp.lineTo(b.x,b.y);
                         gp.lineTo(c.x,c.y);
                         gp.lineTo(d.x,d.y);
                         gp.closePath();
                         return gp;
                    }
                    private void drawShape(Graphics2D g,Shape shape){
                        AffineTransform oldt=g.getTransform();
                        Rectangle2D bounds=shape.getBounds2D();
                        double height=bounds.getHeight();
                        double width=bounds.getWidth();
                        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));
                        g.translate(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2);
                        g.translate(-width/2,-height/2);
                        g.draw(shape.getBounds2D());
                        g.draw(shape);
                        g.setTransform(oldt);
                }
                    public void paintComponent(Graphics g2){
                            super.paintComponent(g2);
                            Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)g2;
                            drawShape(g,trapezium);
                            //drawShape(g,parallelogram);
                    }
                    public static void main(String args[]){
                            JFrame jf=new JFrame();
                            TestPanel tp=new TestPanel();
                            jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                            jf.add(tp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            jf.setSize(500,500);
                            jf.setVisible(true);
                    }
             }
```

Any help would be appreciated
**EDIT:**
I just removed the confusing lines out of the code...

Comment: passing `Point` objects that you overwrite into your factories is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @MelNicholson that could be a bad idea but that doesn't seem to be a problem. I removed those lines and tried with no improvement....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to account for the bounded x/y location of the Shape:

```
Rectangle bounds=shape.getBounds(); // changed this
...
//g.translate(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2);
//g.translate(-width/2,-height/2);
g.translate((this.getWidth() - width) / 2,(this.getHeight() - height) / 2);
g.translate(-bounds.x, -bounds.y); // added this
```

Comment: Did the down voter even try this code? Please explain the reason why this is not an acceptable solution. I feel it is better than the accepted answer because all the translations are done in one place. In fact the accepted answer only works because the bounds.x value happens to be 0 (otherwise you would need to manipulate a.x as well). This solution will work in all cases.

Comment: yours is perfect that's what I want. I wanted to create my shape assuming my own system and paint it translated....

Comment: @mKorbel you mean what? I didn't downvote it...my rep wasn't high enough for that few minutes ago...

Comment: @camickr can you just explain what I did wrong and what's the difference between your code and mine. Also, using getBounds2D instead of getBounds makes any difference?

Comment: his answer was (probalby) down_voted, now there isn't any downvoting :-)

Comment: @pinkpanther, When you use a GeneralPath it can calculate its own x/y values for the Shape, so the origin isn't (0, 0) as you might expect. The translate is then used to get the origin back to (0, 0). From there your other translation is used to center the Shape within the panel. Rectangle2D shouldn't make any difference. Just add a println() statement to see the actual Rectangle(2D) used by the 
shape.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:
In method `rhombusFactory()`, change that:

```
a.y=0;
```

to this:

```
a.y=height/2;
```

*Short expanation*:
In your `drawShape()` method, you place the graphics context's origin where you assume that the upper left corner of the shape's bounds would be (Point: [(getWidth-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2]). In your `rhombusFactory()` method, you set point `a` at (0, 0), which consequently shifts your shape's upper left corner at (0,-height/2), effectively causing it's not being vertically centered.

Comment: (OK, stop banging your head against the wall now. It happens to the best of us (or so I have been told :P).)

Comment: that's ok is there any other thing that's preventing my trapezium from centering....

Comment: @pinkpanther: Actually it is your rhombus that is not centered. See my updated answer. (Your trapezium is placed just fine.)

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly, but why?. When I'm just placing with respect to bounding rectangle why does it matter?                    my bad, it's midnight here, i said trapezium instead of rhombus....

Comment: See my updated answer for a short explanation (let me know if it does not make sense, I'll try to explain it better).

Comment: You don't need to play with the a.y value. This can all be handled in the translate() when you paint the shape.

Comment: @ExpertSystem yes I also consider explanation for camickr's comment

Answer (score 1):

Your translate is wrong. You should first translate the origin of you drawing space to the center of the panel and then translate the center of your drawing to the origin. You did the latter right, but the first wrong.

Change

```
g.translate(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
g.translate(-width/2,-height/2);
```

to

```
g.translate(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2);
g.translate(-width/2,-height/2);
```

Or just

```
g.translate((this.getWidth() - width) / 2,(this.getHeight() - height) / 2);
```

Comment: yeah sorry, that was by mistake in SSCCE but the actual code contains what you wrote and causing problem with trapezium. So, is this sufficient for centering...or is there anything other than this in my code causing the problem provided that I have translated correctly?

Comment: @pinkpanther yeah, this is enough for centering. It might be indeed that you're reusing `Point` objects in different shapes, like Mel Nicholson mentioned, but maybe that's also just a typo in your SSCCE?