# Center Align a rectangle in Java Frame/Panel

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, repaint, paintcomponent

Trying to create a bull' eyes program using paintComponent. I want the rectangle to be in the center of the screen. How do i do that?

Comment: this is not a place to put your home work there.Please show some code of what you have tried.

Comment: I've asked the question similar to this some days ago there is a robust solution answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637633/aligning-shapes-center-to-jpanels-center

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you draw what ever you want around the center of the component, based on it's width and height

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int width = getWidth() - 1;
    int height = getHeight() - 2;
    g.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);
    g.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);
}
```

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for details

Comment: I guess the real question now is, why the down vote? Because I didn't draw a rectangle? Can't do everything for people, especially when no effort is placed into the question

Comment: +1 for even answering such a question. :-)